# Hikari Connection Pool + Keystore

Tags: keystore, hikaricp

How do I set the below property in Hikari connection pool in SpringBoot(java)? So I am trying to connect to the DB using keystore.

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore",keyStorePath);
```

So basically I tried the below settings which didn't work:

```
config.addDataSourceProperty("trustCertificateKeyStoreUrl",keyStorePath );
```

and

```
config.addDataSourceProperty("keystore",keyStorePath );
```